# Is completeness over a normed space invariant under linear homeomorphisms?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

The question is contained in the title. I know that for metric spaces completeness is not invariant under homeomorphisms. What happens if we consider the same problem in the category of normed spaces with continuous linear maps as morphisms?

Comment: It means that the norms are equivalent..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces and let $f: X \to Y$ be a uniformly continuous homeomorphism. If $Y$ is complete then $X$ is complete.

**Proof sketch:** Let $x_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$. By uniform continuity $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. By completeness, $f(x_n)$ has a limit $y$. Let $x = f^{-1}(y)$, then by continuity of $f$, $x$ is a limit of $x_n$. $\square$

**Corollary:** The affirmative answer to the question follows from the above theorem and the fact that every linear homeomorphism and its inverse are uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces and $T : X \to Y$ is a linear homeomorphism then both $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are uniformly continuous, and hence $X$ is complete if and only if $Y$ is complete.